# triangle regions problem

Tags: geometry

i'm trying to solve this problem from "precalculus in a nutshell" but i can't get my mind around it.

[problem n8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVc58.png)

It's the problem N8.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Draw the segment $DE$. Inverting Thales' Theorem $$DE \mid\mid AB$$
It is a well-known fact that the barycentre of a triangle divides the medians in a ratio of 2:1. Thus, the similarity factor between the triangles $\Delta ABF$ and $\Delta EDF$ is 2. Therefore $$[\Delta ABF]=4·[\Delta EDF]$$where $[...]$ denotes the area of the polygon "..."

Note furthermore that $$[\Delta ABC]=4·[\Delta ECD]$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @J.Melichopulos You can also upvote or accept the answer if you liked it ;)

Comment: Is there an easier way of solving this? just curious, thanks. :P